# Problems when mounting an Ecryptfs folder located on an NFS share

Tags: ubuntu, raspbian, nfs, ecryptfs

This project just keeps getting better

So to describe the scenario, I have a `Raspberry Pi` that transmits `Ecryptfs` Keys to my home server from abroad. There are 2 USB keys required for decryption.

If I want to decrypt remotely, I will insert the 2 USB keys into the `Raspberry Pi`. First, I have the Pi connecting to the server through an `OpenVPN` connection. From there, the main server will mount the USB keys through an `NFS` connection and start the decryption process. **The first USB key decrypts the second USB key, and then the second USB key decrypts the actual data**

**Problem:**
The bold part above is the problem with `NFS`. The keys both mount fine in raw, encrypted form. When the first USB key decrypts the second key, it will decrypt the directory, but I can't read or write;

> cat/ls: "Not accessible":  "Read-only file system"

**Stuff I've Done / Additional Info:**
Usually this type of error relates to `disk/fs` damage. But this is not the case, because I can decrypt and read the data fine when I plug in the keys straight into the main server (not remotely with `NFS`).

When done remotely, /proc/mounts says the `ecryptfs` volume is mounted with RW

I used to use `CIFS` until it kept failing and almost destroyed my root fs, but it actually worked fine with the decryption process

`"ls -la" returns "????"` for owner and group on the decrypted files

**TL;DR: Mounting `Ecryptfs` directories through an NFS share results in a decrypted directory, of which contents are `"Not accessible: Read-only file system"`**